# Multilingual content item sitefinity

Tags: c#, sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I have a dynamic content type with multilingual related properties. I want to create, from code(C#) a content item, then add different translations on the same content item. Is this possible from code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written sample code (tested in version 9.1) some time ago, check it here:

https://gist.github.com/VesselinVassilev/dd63d3b7d02e2fb57dc6370aca4a4c10